# Twilio is sending multiple messages to the same number

Tags: c#, twilio

I am trying to learn how to use Twilio to send SMS, and I am using the sample code from the tutorials. When I run the code, it is sending the message to my phone at least twice. Am I missing something?

Here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

namespace Quickstart
{
class SmsSender
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
        const string accountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        const string authToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        // Initialize the Twilio client
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);


            // Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
            MessageResource.Create(
                from: new PhoneNumber("XXXXXXXXX"), // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
                to: new PhoneNumber("XXXXXXXXX"), // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
                                                 // Message content
                body: $"This is a test.");

            Console.WriteLine($"Sent message to Andrew");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does `Sent message to Andrew` appear twice in the console?

Comment: No, I'm using an Android, LG V20 to be exact. And no, the console only writes once..

Comment: Also, the SMS logs in the account show the message going out twice. I'm really confused..

Comment: Here is from their support site. Don't know if it helps much, just thought I'd chime in. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181768-Why-did-the-person-I-sent-a-message-to-get-duplicate-messages-

Comment: Does this only happen when debugging?  If you run the program without debugging, does it send only once?

Comment: I fixed it, turns out Avast was trying to scan my executable, and it was making it run for a second time. Fixed it by excluding my project folder.

Comment: Avast is super annoying when it comes to that...

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks Avast!